# Format problems with captions

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I have a short caption that looks ugly becuase the "figure" part and the number are stretched from each other.
Should I make just this one caption raggedright and how do I make that? Better option?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}\parindent=10pt
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/dummy}
\captionof{figure}{\ch{[Co(dinosar)]Cl3}.}\label{fig:dummy}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple hack

The quickest way, if this is just relevant for one caption in your document, is to manually insert a linebreak at the very beginning of the caption:

```
\captionof{figure}{\\\ch{[Co(dinosar)]Cl3}.}\label{fig:dummy}
```

## More elegant solution

The `caption` package has a `justification` option. You can use it to have all captions set left-justified with the `raggedright` value (or `RaggedRight` if you want to enable word breaking):

```
\usepackage[format=plain, justification=raggedright]{caption}
```

If you want to have left-justified captions only for a single figure, add instead this line inside the `minipage` environment, before `\captionof`:

```
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
```

More generally, other justifications are possible as well. Supported options include: `justified`, `centering`, `raggedright`, `raggedleft` (see [`caption` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) for details).

## Full example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/dummy}
    \captionof{figure}{\\\ch{[Co(dinosar)]Cl3}.}\label{fig:dummy}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well, that works out; stupid that I didn't try

Comment: do you also know how I would make a specific caption centered/raggedright/whatever?

Comment: I updated my answer including two other ways of achieving this (where other justifications are possible as well). All three options produce for this minimal example the same output.

Comment: Thanxalot! i was aware of the global `justification`option but not how to change it at just one specific place.